# How to refer to an Array outside of scope/menu?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, scope

Hi guys a quick question. Im creating a Java menu below is a sample piece of the code. I am wondering if i set up 2 arrays in an "if" statement how can i refer to these arrays again. I know that because of scope the arrays get destroyed when moved out of the if statement. I wanted to refer to the arrays again if option P is selected.

```
public static void determineOption (char option) {

        if (option == 'A') {

        int class_number = Console.getInt("Enter how many students between 1-10");

        while (class_number < 1 || class_number > 10)
        class_number = Console.getInt("Enter how many students between 1-10");

        System.out.println("");


        String[] name = new String[class_number];
        int[] score = new int[name.length];

        for (int i=0; i<class_number; i=i+1) 
        {
            name[i] = Console.getString("Enter Name");
            score[i] = Console.getInt("Enter score");
        }

        }
        else if (option == 'P') {


        }
```

Comment: Declare your array references outside the `if`, and initialize it inside. Remember, you would also need to initialize your array with a default value outside.

Comment: Umm. wait, you need to tell little bit more. Because, when the array is initialized in your `if`, your `else if` won't be executed. So, there is no point in accessing the created array in `else if`. The array there will be created independent of how you are creating it in `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your logic it seems HashMap is suitable for this.

```
HashMap<String,Integer>
```

Your key is name and value is score. You could define this as class variable and use in both if else if cases.

Answer (score 0):

Put the declaration higher up in the scope, perhaps on the class if necessary. In other words, change the arrays from being variables local to the method to being variables on the class.

Answer (score 0):

Declare that array outside `if` block and initialize it if required.

Answer (score 0):

It's all a matter of scopes. Declare the array outside your `if` statement to put it in the scope of the method itself, that way you'll be able to use it across the method (from its declaration line to the end of the method). If you need to use the array amongst various method you'll probably need to hold to that array a little bit longer by making it a class field.

Just be careful, if your array's initialization depends on different conditions you'll have to do a check before using it, because at any time it might have not been initialized yet.